# Checking model to see if a record exists in Yii-PHP

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am trying to check if a record already exists in the database table using yii. Reading the [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#exists-detail) it says there is a method *exists()* that can be used instead of finding the recording using *findByAttributes()* or *find()*. The benefit being less memory is used because it doesn't have to retrieve the record, it just checks if it exists.

When I try to implement this method like so:

```
    if (UserRsvp::model()->exists(array("user_id"=>$userId))) {
        echo 'Exists';
    } else {
        echo "Doesn't exist";
    }
```

I get an error:
*CException : Property "CDbCriteria.user_id" is not defined.*

If I try to do it the findByAttributes way it works fine (but I want to use exists() to improve efficiency)

```
if(UserRsvp::model()->findByAttributes(array("user_id"=>$userId))) {

  echo 'Exists';
} else {
  echo "Doesn't exist";
}
```

Am I doing something wrong with the exists() method?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use this:

```
UserRsvp::model()->exists('user_id = :user_id', array(":user_id"=>$userId));
```

Comment: this can be used like this : UserRsvp::model()->exists('user_id ='.$userId);

Comment: @sprytechies Not in Yii 1.1.